# Save state of dynamic checkboxes after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a calendar. Based on the chosen date I am loading some checkboxes to display some time slots. The time slots are loaded from the database using PHP.

I am using this to load it dynamically:

```
$(".date-picker-2").datepicker({
minDate: 0,
onSelect: function(dateText) {

 $.ajax({
   method : "POST",
   url : "process.php",
   data : 'date='+ dateText,
   success : function(result){
    $("#slotplace").html(result)
    }
});
}
});
```

The process.php loads something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="M" class="days" value="22/11 9am">9am<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="M" class="days" value="22/11 10am">10am<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="M" class="days" value="22/11 11am">11am<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="M" class="days" value="22/11 12pm">12pm<br>
```

If another date is clicked on the calendar then another set of slots are loaded from the database via AJAX.

With this `$("#slotplace").html(result)` I think it is being overwritten each time.

How can I save the state of those checkboxes that are checked, say on the 22nd, if the user navigates to another day by selecting another date, then clicks back on to the 22nd? Currently it is just replacing I think. I could pass this data to PHP on another `click()` function but was hoping to find something using JQuery to save multiple calls to the server and also to make it more efficient.

Comment: store the information client side using web storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API, or just create a variable and check the new elements when they're added to the DOM

Comment: Do you need them to persist when the page reloads or just while on the current page?  Do you need to ever know the values they clicked?  A solution here can range anywhere from using localstorage, to server side session variables, to getting/setting values in a database.  it really depends on how you intend to use the checked values

Comment: Not on page refresh just whilst the dates are switching. Prefer a JavaScript solution without local storage.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `var selected = []`, get the values of all of the checkboxes checked
2. Send the Ajax call
3. Recheck the checkboxes with the values.